# Synclock in Module Constructor?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, synclock

Coming from Java where Static Block are immediately called. In VB.NET (ASP.NET) a Module Constructor isn't called until the first method is called.  So, this begs the question, if I'm performing initialization within my Module's constructor do I need to wrap it in a Synclock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules are a VB.NET programming nicety.  Once compiled, they are the same as C# static classes, therefore a module constructor is the same as a C# static constructor.  A C# static constructor is presumably exactly the same as a static block in Java.  The documentation states that a C# static constructor is never executed more than once, so that would suggest that no synchronisation is necessary.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I read the following article before posting the question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.80).aspx and the following paragraph caused some confusion (near bottom, Example): "the class Bus has a static constructor and one static member, Drive(). When Drive() is called, the static constructor is invoked to initialize the class." -- Hence leading to the notion that maybe the static constructor doesn't get called until one of it's methods are called first.

Comment: A static constructor doesn't get invoked until the class is used.  Usually, that means before the instance constructor when the first instance is created.  I imagine that it's the same in Java.  In the case of a static class though, there is no instance constructor and there is no instance, so the first time a class is used is when a static member is first invoked.  The static constructor will be implicitly invoked before that member.

Comment: In Java a Static Block is called the instant the Class Loader loads the class into memory, regardless if its ever used or not. Its a cool feature of Tomcat, it ensures all static classes are initialized and ready before they are called. I just did a test and you're right, the static constructor isn't executed until the static class is used. Appreciate the clarification.